# Jquery Mobile Panel Content not Styled

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am adding the entire html markup in the pagebeforecreate method in JQmobile. At last I append the html to the empty page and use trigger('create') to style the  entire markup properly.Everything is styled fine except the panel which comes out of its area.I have tried using trigger.(updateLayout) method of panel but no use. 
I know there is some simple command I am missing but couldn't figure it out .
Looking for  someone's help

[image]

Code:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#pageone', function(){       


        var str = '<div data-role="panel" id="user-panel" data-display="overlay" data-   
                  swipe-close="false" >'+

                   '<ul data-role="listview" id="list" data-theme="a">'

         var str1=''

          $.getJSON( "url", function( data, status) {

           $.each(data.category, function (key, value) {

           if(value.id==2) str = str + '<li  ><a href = "index.html" id="'+value.id+'"   
                                 onclick="test(event)">'+value.name+'</a></li>'

        else str = str + '<li  ><a href = "MainCategory.html" id="'+value.id+'" 
                   onclick="test(event)">'+value.name+'</a></li>'



          });

     str = str + '</ul>'
     str = str +'</div>'
   //Code  continued.....And at last 

  $(str).appendTo( "#pageone" ).enhanceWithin();       
  $("#pageone").trigger("create");
  $("#list").listview().listview('refresh');
  $("#list").listview('refresh');
  $('[data-role=panel]').trigger( "updatelayout" );
```

PS: When I get the generated markup in the console and open it as a html page the panel is fine which means that there is some problem with the dynamic addition

Comment: please add some code that you have tried. This help to solve problem easily.

Comment: please share jsfiddle of it and tell me which panel is going out of its area?